# Try Better counter for views for row-counter export, not showing up in view fields area , this because standard counter doesn't work for export csv

Tags: view, drupal-7, export, drupal-modules

Drupal 7: The standard views counter "Global: View result counter" doesn't work with export views results to csv. This is also a problem in Drupal 8, but I want to solve it still in Drupal 7 to Migrate.
See Drupal 8 issue: https://www.drupal.org/project/vbo_export/issues/3184888
I need the counter to export the row-counter with the other data.

I am trying to migrate Drupal 7 view-result to Drupal 10, and therefor I need a certain amount of nodes (1000+), to export. And I need to do this in batch because of memory usage. The 1000+ nodes have more than 20 fields each, including addresses. And to know if all batches are exported I need the row-count.

EDIT: With the following code I got the handler showing, but  now error occurs, and no data showing:
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in theme_views_mini_pager() (line 1092 of /sites/all/modules/views/theme/theme.inc

but I am not able to get the custom view field handler to work to get a correct row-counter and with this row-counter a correct csv exported. EDIT: the handler is now showing.

I tried other methods to use views_php or views custom field to set a row counter on the view. It works on screen, but when I export the view, the row-counter in the csv is for every row 1!

I tried to build a custom views module with the better counter from Drupal 8 issue: https://www.drupal.org/project/vbo_export/issues/3184888

**viewsbatchcounter.info
**

```
name = Views Batchcounter
description = Provides a batchcounter handler for Views
core = 7.x
package = Views
dependencies[] = views
files[] = views/viewsbatchcounter_handler_bettercounter.inc`
```

**viewsbatchcounter.module
**

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_views_api().
 */
function viewsbatchcounter_views_api() {
  return array(
    'api' => 3,
    'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'viewsbatchcounter') . '/views',
  );
}
```

**viewsbatchcounter.views.inc
**

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_views_data_alter().
 */
function viewsbatchcounter_views_data_alter(&$data) {
  $data['node']['bettercounter'] = array(
    'title' => t('Batchcounter'),
    'help' => t('Count result based on offset generated by batch 
processing.'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'viewsbatchcounter_handler_bettercounter',
    ),
  );
}
```

**viewsbatchcounter_handler_bettercounter.inc
**

```
<?php

// This file must be at viewsbatchcounter/views directory.

/**
 * Result counter for views processed in batch.
 *
 * @ingroup views_field_handlers
 *
 * @ViewsField("bettercounter")
 */
class viewsbatchcounter_handler_bettercounter extends 
views_handler_field {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getValue(ResultRow $values, $field = NULL) {
    // Note:  1 is subtracted from the counter start value below 
because the
    // counter value is incremented by 1 at the end of this 
function.
    $count = is_numeric($this->options['counter_start']) ? $this- >options['counter_start'] - 1 : 0;

    // Get the current offset.
    if (!empty($this->query->offset)) {
    $offset = $this->query->offset;
    }
    // Add the counter for the current site.
    $count += $offset + $this->view->row_index + 1;

    return $count;
  }

}
```

So I hoped with this custom views module for drupal 7 with better counter will solve the problem so I can batch export the views result to files and see the row-counter as such I know all rows are exported to csv.

But I can't get the custom view field to work?

Greetings and thanks for your reply in advance

Comment: Hi, this doesn't seems to work correcty in drupal 7
   // Get the current offset.
       if (!empty($this->query->offset)) {
       $offset = $this->query->offset;
       }