# Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in theme_views_mini_pager() (line 1092 of sites/all/modules/views/theme/theme.inc

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-modules

I finally got my views field handler showing, but somewhere there is a code error. I got the code from a Drupal 8 example: https://www.drupal.org/project/vbo_export/issues/3184888 but I got in Drupal 7 the following error:
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in theme_views_mini_pager() (line 1092 of /sites/all/modules/views/theme/theme.inc

The code is from [Try Better counter for views for row-counter export, not showing up in view fields area , this because standard counter doesn't work for export csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76211445/try-better-counter-for-views-for-row-counter-export-not-showing-up-in-view-fie) on which I finally have the field handler showing, but how to solve this notice and therefor got my data from the view back?

I tried lots of things to get the $offset populated, but may be it is a Drupal 8 -> Drupal 7 thing?